# How to send a file from client to server along with its file name using tcp/ip?

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, file-io

I am sending a file from client to server along with its file name using TCP/IP. I have developed code, but I am not able to receive the file. I am giving the code for reference.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<unistd.h>
 #include<string.h>    
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<sys/ioctl.h>
 #include<sys/types.h>
 #include<arpa/inet.h>
 #include<sys/socket.h>
 int receive_text(long long int socket)
 { 
    long int buffersize = 0, recv_size = 0, size = 0, read_size,    write_size; 
    char verify = '1',c; 
    int errno;
    FILE *text;
    char *pch;
    char *str="/home/sosdt009/Documents";
    char *fname[2];
    char *filename[10];
    char *filebody[1024];
    int i=0;

    //Find the size of the text
    recv(socket, (char *)&size, sizeof(int), 0);
    printf("Size value is:%ld\n",size);
    //Send our verification signal
    send(socket, &verify, sizeof(char), 0);
    printf("Size value is:%ld\n",size);
    //Make sure that the size is bigger than 0
    if (size <= 0)
    {
        printf("Error has occurred. Size less than or equal to 0 \n");
        return -1;
    } 

    //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet
    while (recv_size < size)
    {
        ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
      //We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket 
      if (buffersize > 0)
      {
        char *pBuf = malloc(buffersize);
        printf("Buffer value is:%s\n",pBuf);
        if (!pBuf)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory Error. Cannot allocate!\n");
            exit(-1);
        } 
        read_size = recv(socket, pBuf, buffersize, 0);
        printf("read size is:%ld\n",read_size);
        if (read_size  < 0)
        {
            printf("%s", strerror(errno));
        }
        //printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n");
        pch = strtok (pBuf,"@");
        printf(" value is:%s\n",pch);
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            filename[i]=pch;
            strcpy(str,filename[i]);
            printf("the string copy is: %s\n",str);
            text = fopen(str, "w"); 
                /*printf ("filename=%s\n",filename[i]);
            pch = strtok (NULL, "@");*/
            i++;
            filebody[i]=pch;
                printf ("filebody=%s\n",filebody[i]);
            pch = strtok (NULL, "@");
            while ((filebody[i] = strtok(NULL, "@")) != NULL)
            printf("Next: %s\n",filebody[1024]);
            //strcpy(filename[i],"filename");
            //strcpy(filebody[i],pBuf);
            //strcat(filename[i],filebody[i]);
            pBuf=filename[i];
        }       

        //Write the currently read data into our text file
        write_size = fwrite(pBuf, 1, buffersize, text); 
        free(pBuf);

        //Increment the total number of bytes read
        recv_size += read_size;
      }
    } 
    fclose(text);
    printf("File successfully Received! \n");
    return 1;
 }
 int main(int argc , char *argv[])
 {
    long long int socket_desc , new_socket, c, read_size, buffer = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char *readin;

    //Create socket

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
       printf("Could not create socket");
    }

  //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  server.sin_port = htons( 6777 );

  //Bind

 if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server ,sizeof(server)) < 0)
 {
   puts("bind failed");
   return 1;
 }
 puts("Bind completed");

 //Listen

 listen(socket_desc,3);

  //Accept and incoming connection

  puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
  c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  if((new_socket = accept(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t *)&c)))
  {
    puts("Connection accepted");
  }
  fflush(stdout);
  if (new_socket<0)    
  {
    perror("Accept Failed");
    return 1;
  }
    receive_text(new_socket);
    close(socket_desc);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish with this code is really unclear.

If I am correct, the code posted above is receiving data from the client and the loops process the data by storing storing some data in "filename" and "filebody" arrays respectively. You then try to open each filename and store its corresponding body data in a text file.

I think the problem is with the inner for loop where you are opening the file with each iteration. Since you are opening the file with the second arg as 'w' (writeable), you are overwriting hence deleting the existing content of the file. This may cause it to appear to have not received the file from the client.

Try opening the text file with the second argument as 'a' (append) instead of writeable and closing the file with each iteration. Also consider moving the statement:

```
    write_size = fwrite(pBuf, 1, buffersize, text);
```

In the inner while loop.

Comment: I have used append mode and also moved fwrite into while loop, i am only able to receive the file name, but the contents are missing

Comment: Are you able to receive the body (contents) over the network? If so then just add another fwrite function for the body because rightn ow you are only writing the filename to the text file.

Comment: No i am not able to receive the contents. If you look into the code above, after the statemt  pch = strtok (pBuf,"@");   printf(" value is:%s\n",pch);, the  text file name is printed and after this i am getting segmentation fault.

Comment: Is the code written in while loop is correct? I just want to confirm

Comment: The code seg faults because i increments to a value > 10. Could you update your code, only then can i see if the code is correct.